Is it likely that gradient flow trajectories of a $G$-invariant function pass through degenerate points?
This question may be posed somewhat vaguely, but I'm interested to actually get an idea of what to expect, so I try to not target it at a specific result.
Assume that $G$ is a compact Lie group, acting on a smooth compact manifold $M$, and let $f:M\to \mathbb R$ be a $G$-invariant Morse function on $M$. What I'm wondering is, whether one should expect that a gradient flow trajectory of $f$ with starting point sampled uniformly from $M$ has nontrivial probability to pass through degenerate points.
A degenerate point is a point $x\in M$ such that the $G$-action is not free on the $G$-orbit of $x$.
I'm not sure if the question is well posed this way, because maybe not much can be said without further hypotheses on $f$. In case adding this helps, I'd like to know what happens for "typical", very regular and well controlled, functions $f$.
If not an answer/formulation, I would also appreciate a good reference where this kind of topic is developed.

Wait action of any group is transitive on any of its orbits.

To the OP: following up on the comment above, in your definition of "degenerate point" did you perhaps mean to say the G-action isn't free?

That's right, sorry for the typo, I edited it
